# I ask for an explanation about the なの in [祖母は耳が遠い、つまり、耳が少し不自由**なの**だ。]

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, particle-の, sentence-final-particles

1. Is なの considered as a whole (grammatical expression)?
2. Or is it な ,to make 不自由 an adj, and の seperately?
   If 2) is the case, what does の mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Here の　is used in the same manner as you might こと, as a nominalizer(sp?)

It is common to end a sentence with ことだ or のだ basically turning the sentence structure into " it is the case(thing) that ..."

Effectively there is little difference in the meaning than if it was not there at all, but it can have connotations of politeness, so for instance in the sentence you have given, there is an implicit respect for the Grandmother.

This 文法 is used all over the place, and if you spend much time in conversation you may find yourself doing it without thinking.

Comment: What about the Na before that No?
By the way, i'm sorry, but i didn't understand what u meant by (sp?).

Comment: (Sp?= I am not sure on spelling)

Comment: ok so the な attaches to your なadj.
大きな車　⇒　 お兄ちゃんの車は大きなの。(大きいcan be both なor いadj)
早い車 　⇒　 お兄ちゃんの車は早いの。

Comment: Sorry for another, but there is also a connotation of teaching or informing when なのis used, kind of like だよ.